# How to refresh the data according to the user after logging in without reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a react and redux app in which the user needs to be logged in to create a post. However, if he forgets to login and starts writing the post and press create button a login modal appears to him. Now, I don't want him to lose what he wrote by reloading the page after he logs in, and yet I need to refresh the data of the app to be displayed according to the logged user.
So what is the best method to be used in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the simplest solution is to not let people type posts unless they're logged in. Have something like "Log in to create a post" where the post input would normally be.

If you still want the solution in your question, then you can use [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp). So if the login succeeds, then save whatever they've typed into `localStorage` before reloading the page. In your React component, during the mounting logic, you can check if there's anything in `localStorage` in the corresponding property name you're saving it under. If not, just render the empty input. If there is a post saved there, load what they'd typed into the input and clear the `localStorage`. Now they're logged in, the page is refreshed and their post content has been reloaded into the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an action/reducer that'll store the message into redux.

If the user isn't logged in and press the button that creates the post, you can dispatch an action to keep the form entries in the store and retrieve it with a selector after the user is logged in and if he typed in the form.

Another good alternative is to use `Window.localStorage`